# Nested_attributes not deleted rails 4 with strong_params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using gem 'nested_form' form my rails application, but i have a problem and it's was weird.

this is my model, e.g:

```
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :spot_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :spot_items, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destory: true
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Spot

  mount_uploader :image, ImageImageUploader
end

class SpotItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Spot

  mount_uploader :avatar, ChildImageUploader
end
```

In my spots_controller.rb, i was set strong params

```
def parent_params
  params.require(:spot).permit(:name, :images_attributes => [:id, :image, :_destroy], :spot_items_attributes => [:id, :name, :age, :image, :_destroy])
end
```

In create all fucntion work well, when edit i wanna delete one record from each nested model when i submit in show everything look fine, but when i edit again the record from nested still exist but only for childs, record from images is gone.

Do any one can give me some clue?

Comment: for which of the models doesn't it work? If its the case for `Child`, I think you should write `:children_attributes` instead of `childs_attributes`. Could you maybe add the filtered params using `permit`?

Comment: For child model, it's doesn't work. can you explain me about filtered params?

Comment: I think your problem is that the plural of child in rails is **children** and not **childs**. try it out!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question any more after the update.